# op amp n-type with additional resistor and current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, fet

I have an op-amp using n-type FET with current source.
I have several questions on these circuit: 
1. Operation of circuit 
2. Equivalent circuit
3. Av, Ai, Zin, Zout 
Since this circuit has additional resistor compared to the original one, i'm quite confused. 
[image: Circuit 2]
[image: Circuit 3]

Answer (score 0):

You have, of course, a mix of Nch and Pch. This is classic diffpair Nch XM1+XM2 feeding the Pch differential-to-single-ended XM3+XM4.

The "X" output node is result of deltaIout *  ro6 ||rp7; the fixed pulldown current from XM6 is partially compensated by voltage drop across XR3 (10Kohm).

Without knowing KN and KP (uA/volt^2), we cannot compute the amps/volt of the differential pairs or current-mirrors. Without Rout of the two output drains, we cannot convert all that internal transconductance into an output voltage gain.

Zin? Its imbalanced. No Miller effect[OK 2:1] on left input; maybe huge Miller effect on right input.

Ai? current gain? in a FETinput circuit? infinite.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
However, I'm still quite confused about this circuit.
Can you describe how this works, please? 
I'm quite helpless :( 
Thanks in advance